# Is Anyone familiar with rotation errors after export?

Tags: import, unity

IM made a turret style with a spinning chamber, when I export to external Animations softwares like sketchfab's profile renderer the entire mesh spins with the chamber.How do I separate the rotations IN BLENDER?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you export? As FBX or try Alembic

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I exported in FBX. Will exporting in Alembic affect Unity at all?

Comment: Thanks that fixed it

Comment: cool you're welcome!